# Why don't the other Greybeards Speak?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've noticed that out of all the Greybeards currently living in Tamriel, only Arnegir and Paarthurnax are able to/choose to speak English. The others (Borri, Einarth, and Wulfgar) only speak in the dragon tongue. Is there a specific reasoning for this? I'm unable to find an answer on the wiki.

Comment: Not an answer, but related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295234/how-did-the-greybeards-learn-shouts/295236#295236

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Greybeards)

> If the Dragonborn attempts to engage in conversation with any of the Greybeards in High Hrothgar besides Arngeir, they simply respond with a respectful greeting—"Dovahkiin" and a gentle bow. When they speak, the building tremors and if outside, a loud, distant bell can be heard. Arngeir can be asked to elaborate on the reason why none of the Greybeards can be engaged in conversation. **The reason is that the other Greybeards' voices are so powerful that even a whisper could kill a man**.

Comment: "even a whisper could kill a man" yet they say "Dovahkiin" when talked to.